# Creating a database for a Telescope Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to create a telescope meteor.js app. I tried to deploy to Mudulus and everything went well but the site doesn't load. After searching I realize it's because I don't have any database (sorry I'm new). What's the best way to set up a database for Meteor?

Comment: you should make some effort first. there are lot of databases which can be used to do so.

Comment: got it, but when I run the telescope app it says starting mongodb, so I'm assuming that it means that I have a built in mongodb system? I'm sorry I read through the telescope docs already but couldn't find anything on it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step post to deploy to Modulus:

https://medium.com/@david_sykora/taking-meteor-apps-into-production-with-modulus-compose-and-codeship-54236d7f0cc